# Equation of the Sphere inscribed in a Tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

Find the Equation of the Sphere , inscribed in a Tetrahedron whose faces are $$ x =0 , y=0 , z = 0, x + 2y + 2z =1 $$

Let $(a,b,c)$ be the centre and $r$ be the radius of the Sphere.

Since the Sphere inscribed in a Tetrahedron, thus the Length of the Perpendicular from the center $(a,b,c)$ upon each of the face = radius of the Sphere.

Length of the perdicular distance from the point $(a,b,c)$ on the plane $lx+my +nz +k = 0$ is $\frac{| la +mb +nc +k|} {\sqrt {l^2 +m^2 + n^2} }$

Thus $a=b = c = \frac{|a +2b +2c -1| }{\sqrt{a^2 +4b^2 +4c^2}}$

There are two cases arise, we get two two Spheres whose centers $c_1$ and $c_2$ and radius $r_1$ and $r_2$, where $c_1 = (1/8, 1/8, 1/8)$, $r_1 = 1/8$ and $c_2 = (1/2 , 1/2 , 1/2 )$ , $r_2 = 1/2$

I think we can inscribed in a tetrahedron only one sphere

So please tell me which case can  reject. what is the reason behind rejection. Thank you

Comment: $c_2$ is outside the tetrahedron, the sphere centered at $c_2$ with radius $r_2$ is an exshere. The sphere you want is the insphere, centered at $c_1$ with radius $r_1$.

Comment: How can we prove that the sphere centered at $c_2$ is outside the tetrahedron.

Comment: The value of the function $x + 2y + 2z - 1$ has opposite sign at $c_2$ and at the origin.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, One question also i want to ask , Is it possible a Sphere which is outside the Tetrahedron and touches all the faces of the tetrahedron

Comment: No, there are only one sphere which touches all 4 faces of a tetrahedron. There are other spheres which touch the planes holding the faces of the tetrahedron but not the faces directly.